# Select a variable offset.resize.copy

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what i am doing wrong with the below code?

```
sub AVERAGE()
   Set dDate = Worksheets("Formula").Range("A1")
   Set rcell = Worksheets("Bond Status - Total Stats").Range("B5:NE5") _
      .Find(What:=dDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
   If rcell Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Date " & dDate & " not found in Bond Status - Total Stats"
   Else
      rcell.Offset(1).Resize(-18, 15).Select.Copy 'this line is not working
      Worksheets("Formula").Range("F2:W2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
   End If
End Sub
```

What i am trying to do is copy a range of data to the left and down 15 rows from date as defined by `Worksheets("Formula").Range("A1")`. I just cant seem to get past the resize.
The line that is commented is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to call the `Copy` method on the `Select` method of a `Range`.  Select returns a `Variant`, which probably doesn't expose a `Copy` method even though the run-time type is probably a `Range`.

It's not really necessary to `Select` a `Range` before you `Copy` it, as in `.Select.Copy`

I would change this line:

```
rcell.Offset(1).Resize(-18, 15).Select.Copy
```

to

```
rcell.Offset(1).Resize(-18, 15).Copy
```

unless you need that `Range` to be selected.  In which case, you could do this:

```
rcell.Offset(1).Resize(-18, 15).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Another thing to consider is that when doing a `.Find(What:=dDate...` you're trying to search a `Range` for a `Range` object when you're probably wanting to search for a `Date` or `String` value.  The compiler is okay with this because the `What` parameter of the `Find` method expects a `Variant`.  In the first line of the method:

```
Set dDate = Worksheets("Formula").Range("A1")
```

should instead set `dDate` to the `Value` of the `Range` instead of the `Range` itself.  Like so:

```
dDate = Worksheets("Formula").Range("A1").Value
```

Hope this helps.